# url encoding php data into json object

Tags: javascript, php, json, urlencode, authorize.net

Please read - this isn't just simply doing json_encode from php to javascript.

Our billing system uses Authorize.net.  Using the Authorize.net API, in PHP we create a token request.  The data in the request passes customer info, balance, billing address, etc - that data is sent directly with PHP.  In response we get a token to be processed in PHP - and then that token is embedded into the HTML form input.

After the credit card form is submitted, we get a javascript json response back to the form to be processed by other JS functions.  All works fine until we have a customer with the `&` in their company name (IE: `Bar & Grill`)

The `&` triggers an error only in the json response back to the form - specifically the error we get is: `unexpected end of json input` which causes the rest of the scripts to error out.

So, the issue is, does the customer data in the PHP token request need to be urlencoded - or is there a special way to handle the json response?  From what I can tell, Authorize simply returns the exact customer data in the json response - so if we url encode it on the front end (before the token request is sent), then does that mean we also need to url decode the json response.

Its kind of a chicken and an egg which came first problem.

Authorize.net Token Request (in PHP):

```
    $customerData = new AnetAPI\CustomerDataType();
    $customerData->setType("business");
    $customerData->setId($ss['authCustID']);
    $customerData->setEmail($ii['cEmail']);
    
    // Set the Bill To info for new payment type
    $billTo = new AnetAPI\CustomerAddressType();
    $billTo->setFirstName($ii['cFirstName']);
    $billTo->setLastName($ii['cLastName']);
    $billTo->setCompany($ii['cName']);            // #1  <----- IE: "Bar & Grill"
    $billTo->setAddress($ii['cAddress']. " " .$ii['cAddress1']);
    $billTo->setCity($ii['cCity']);
    $billTo->setState($ii['cState']);
    $billTo->setZip($ii['cZip']);
    $billTo->setCountry("USA");

    // set shipping profile
    $shipTo = clone $billTo ;

    // extend billTop profile
    $billTo->setFaxNumber('8005551212') ;
    $billTo->setPhoneNumber($ii['cPhone']);
    
    //create a transaction
    $transactionRequestType = new AnetAPI\TransactionRequestType();
    $transactionRequestType->setTransactionType("authCaptureTransaction");
    $transactionRequestType->setAmount($ss['balance']);
    $transactionRequestType->setCustomer($customerData) ;
    $transactionRequestType->setOrder($order) ;
    $transactionRequestType->setBillTo($billTo) ;
    $transactionRequestType->setShipTo($shipTo) ;

    // Build transaction request
    $request = new AnetAPI\GetHostedPaymentPageRequest();
    $request->setMerchantAuthentication($merchantAuthentication);
    $request->setRefId($refId);
    $request->setTransactionRequest($transactionRequestType);

//execute request
    $controller = new AnetController\GetHostedPaymentPageController($request);
    $response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse(\net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::PRODUCTION);  // SANDBOX or PRODUCTION
    
    $gToken=[] ;
    if (($response != null) && ($response->getMessages()->getResultCode() == "Ok")) {
        //echo $response->getToken()."\n";
        $gToken["Error"]  = 0 ;
        $gToken["Token"] = $response->getToken() ;
    } else {
        //echo "ERROR :  Failed to get hosted payment page token\n";
        $errorMessages = $response->getMessages()->getMessage();
        //echo "RESPONSE : " . $errorMessages[0]->getCode() . "  " .$errorMessages[0]->getText() . "\n";
        $gToken["Error"]  = 1 ;
        $gToken["errMsg"] = $errorMessages[0]->getCode() . ":  " .$errorMessages[0]->getText() ;
    }
```

Form/JSON response handler:

```
AuthorizeNetPopup.onReceiveCommunication = function (querystr) {
  var params = parseQueryString(querystr);
  //console.log(params) ;
  switch (params["action"]) {
    case "successfulSave":
      AuthorizeNetPopup.closePopup();
      break;
    case "cancel":
      AuthorizeNetPopup.closePopup();
      break;
    case "transactResponse":
      // 'response' is a string value
      // encode it as an object, to be passed to global function
      // that will decode it again for PHP
      console.log(params["response"]) ;
      var response = JSON.parse(params["response"]);  // #2 <--- ERROR: unexpected end of json input
      //var response = params["response"];
      httpReceipt(response) ;
      AuthorizeNetPopup.closePopup();
      break;
    case "resizeWindow":
      var w = parseInt(params["width"]);
      var h = parseInt(params["height"]);
      var ifrm = document.getElementById("iframeAuthorizeNet");
      ifrm.style.width = w.toString() + "px";
      ifrm.style.height = h.toString() + "px";
      centerPopup();
      break;
  }
};
```

Do I url encode data at #1 (in php section) or do I url encode the json response before processing it (at #2) - or both?  Very confused on how to handle this.  Do we need to encode the data of eachparameter being added to the token request - or can we just encode the entire request before its submitted? Regardless of which end of the communication gets encoding/decoding applied, what are the proper encoding/decoding calls?

## UPDATE

To illustrate flow:

1. paymentPage.html ->PHP generates token, embeds token into page form, also has iframe for `paymentPageFrame.html`
2. paymentPageFrame.html -> iFrame communicator page, relays msgs between paymentPage.html and authorize.net
3. paymentPage.html -> javascript `onReceiveCommunication` to process messages coming from paymentPageFrame.html

Turns out that authorize.net is returning a URL string to paymentPageFrame.html - the string is not urlencoded.  The string is then getting passed back to the parent `onReceiveCommunication` at which point its being parsed with a custom parser:

```
function parseQueryString(str) {
  var vars = [];
  var arr = str.split('&');
  var pair;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    pair = arr[i].split('=');
    vars.push(pair[0]);
    vars[pair[0]] = unescape(pair[1]);
  }
  return vars;
}
```

This custom parser is then causing a data value that has the `&` in it (IE: "company" : "Bar & Grill") to split the name in half ultimately leading to the invalid/unexpected end of json input.

The `string` being passsed back to the iFrame, which in turn gets passed to the parent is:

```
action=transactResponse&response={"accountType":"Visa","accountNumber":"XXXX0623","transId":"62830720474","responseCode":"1","authorization":"185778","shipTo":{"firstName":"Bob","lastName":"Jones","company":"Backyard Bar & Grill","address":"123 Main St ","city":"Tampa","state":"FL","zip":"33606","country":"USA"},"orderDescription":"2020-12-01 bill for All Regions/All Sites","customerId":"1002-0","totalAmount":"1.50","orderInvoiceNumber":"11386-0","dateTime":"2/2/2021 4:57:53 PM","refId":"ref1612285039"}
```

Now that the string is in the parent page, I am trying to figure the best way to encode it then parse it so it won't break on parsing when a data value has `&` in it (IE: `Backyard Bar & Grill`)

So far I am trying, without sucess:

```
var urlstr = encodeURIComponent(response) ;  // encode it first
var newUrl = new URLSearchParams(urlstr) ; // then proper parse it
```

But when I try to access the parameters, it returns null:

```
consoole.log(newUrl.get('action')) ;  
> null
```

Comment: Does the `onReceiveCommunication` JS-function get called somehow when your PHP code responds (the one we see above) via AJAX or does it call a unknown API (from authorize.net?) that we can not see the code of here?

Comment: @ArSeN - when the html page loads, the php part builds the token request and sends the token request via the authorize.net api.  It gets the token response which is then embedded in the form as the rest of the html page loads.  The html form calls `action="https://accept.authorize.net/payment/payment"` - passing the token as a hidden input. The user clicks "next/pay now" button calling the authorize script opens an iFrame where the users enters the CC info.  That iFrame is passing communications from authroiz.net back to the original html/form page using `onReceiveCommunication`.

Comment: So basically `onReceiveCommunication` is called with data from authorize.net which you have no control over? Sounds like it might be an issue on their end then. Can you possibly show the data (an example) you are working with? e.g. `console.log(params)` at the start of the function?

Comment: @ArSeN - see update in OP.

Comment: Can you show the "the string" that  "is not urlencoded" please, i.e. `str`? It think this should be solveable by some custom regex magic.

Comment: @ArSeN - string and attempts to properly encode it and parse it are added to OP....but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you split on the `&` characters which is also inside the JSON response. For a quick solution I suggest something like:

```js
var str = 'action=transactResponse&response={"accountType":"Visa","accountNumber":"XXXX0623","transId":"62830720474","responseCode":"1","authorization":"185778","shipTo":{"firstName":"Bob","lastName":"Jones","company":"Backyard Bar & Grill","address":"123 Main St ","city":"Tampa","state":"FL","zip":"33606","country":"USA"},"orderDescription":"2020-12-01 bill for All Regions/All Sites","customerId":"1002-0","totalAmount":"1.50","orderInvoiceNumber":"11386-0","dateTime":"2/2/2021 4:57:53 PM","refId":"ref1612285039"}';

var response = JSON.parse(str.replace('action=transactResponse&response=', ''));
console.log(response);
console.log(response.shipTo.company);
```

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vx9zr1b7/

This just replaces away the first parameter and the name of the second, so only the value of the second (and thereby the value of "response") will remain. Note that this only works under the assumption that the response is always in this very same format, and does not have any additional parameters in the response.

I suggest you put it inside your `case "transactResponse":` block.

This will parse you the JSON:

```json
{
  accountNumber: "XXXX0623",
  accountType: "Visa",
  authorization: "185778",
  customerId: "1002-0",
  dateTime: "2/2/2021 4:57:53 PM",
  orderDescription: "2020-12-01 bill for All Regions/All Sites",
  orderInvoiceNumber: "11386-0",
  refId: "ref1612285039",
  responseCode: "1",
  shipTo: {
    address: "123 Main St ",
    city: "Tampa",
    company: "Backyard Bar &amp; Grill",
    country: "USA",
    firstName: "Bob",
    lastName: "Jones",
    state: "FL",
    zip: "33606"
  },
  totalAmount: "1.50",
  transId: "62830720474"
}
```

Note that the `&` became an `&amp;` in the process of parsing the JSON. Therefore, if you are doing anything else with it than just displaying it in the browser, I suggest you `html_entity_decode()` the value on the PHP side.

Comment: thanks.  The dual url parameters with a json string as a parameter value was just messing things up.  I rewrote the parsing function to be able to grab everything, parameters/values and any the response json.  Posting my answer in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

After much tinkering around, i finally wrote my own parser that:

A: if exists, capture the response JSON first

B: then parse the remainder of the URL params:

C: return all params and response object as a single object

```
var str = 'action=transactResponse&response={"accountType":"Visa","accountNumber":"XXXX0623","transId":"62830720474","responseCode":"1","authorization":"185778","shipTo":{"firstName":"Preston","lastName":"Rolinger","company":"Backyard & Grill","address":"2808 W Foster Ave S ","city":"Tampa","state":"FL","zip":"33611","country":"USA"},"orderDescription":"2020-12-01 bill for All Regions/All Sites","customerId":"1002-0","totalAmount":"1.50","orderInvoiceNumber":"11386-0","dateTime":"2/2/2021 4:57:53 PM","refId":"ref1612285039"}&moreKey="other value"' ;

  function parseResponse(str) {
    var resInfo = [], res = {} ;
    if (str.match("&response=")) {
      var params = str.split("&response=") ; // leading params & response obj
      if (params[1].match("}&")) {
        resInfo = params[1].split("}&") ;  // splits off anything at end of obj
        res.response = JSON.parse(resInfo[0] + "}") ;  // add } to complete obj string again
      } else {
        res.response = JSON.parse(params[1]) ;  // else it already is the json string
      }
      if (resInfo[1]) {
        params = params[0]+ "&" +resInfo[1] ;  // join url params back together  
      } else {
        params = params[0] ;
      }
    }  else {
      params = str ;  // else the str has no "response" in it, process just params
    }
    params = new URLSearchParams(encodeURI(params)) ;  //encode then parse
    params.forEach(function(value, key) {
      res[key] = value ;
    }) ;

    return res ;
  }     
var response = parseResponse(str) ;
console.log(response) ;
```